# Javascript String.replace with dynamic regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code, which works, but I need to inject some different stuff into the regular expression object (`regex2`) at runtime. However, text.replace does not seem to like a string object for the regular expression, so how can I make this work?

```
var regex2 = /\|\d+:\d+/;
document.write("result = " + text.replace(regex2, '') + "<br>");
```

Comment: change stringObj to String. If its a string its already an object - aka ATM machine, Pin number etc.

Comment: Must the .replace() call happen within the document.write() call?  Could you not assign that value before you call document.write?  Seems like that would solve the problem (unless I'm not understanding your question correctly).

Comment: I'm Alex's coworker. The stringObj was just to make it clear what we were doing, not the actual code.

Comment: @inkedmn no, that wouldn't make any difference... we still wouldnt be able to pass the replace method a string for the regex. CMS's answer is correct though, it's all taken care of.

Answer (score 70):

You can make a regular expression object from a string using the [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor function:

```
var regExp = new RegExp(myString);  // regex pattern string

text.replace(regExp, '');
```

Comment: Worth noting: *myString* is the regular expression with NO begin and end marker, i.e. not "/foo[123]/", but "foo[123]".

Answer (score 38):

Addition to CMS:
The `RegExp` constructor has an second optional parameter flags
[(15.10.4 The RegExp Constructor)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf#page=203&zoom=100)

```
var text = "This is a Test.";

var myRegExp = new RegExp('teST','i');

text.replace(myRegExp,'Example');
// -> "This is a Example."
```

as Flags you can set

- g -> global search (all occurrences)
- i -> case insensitive
- m -> multiline

Comment: You have to construct the string dynamically and then supply the flags in second param.
new RegExp("^"+dynamic+"+|"+dynamic+"+$","g").

Answer (score 6):

```
var value = "2012-09-10";
value = value.replace(/([0-9]{4})[\/-]([0-9]{2})[\/-]([0-9]{2})/,"$3/$2/$1");
alert(value);
```

this will show

```
10/09/2012
```

Answer (score -5):

you can use eval to,

```
new RegExp( eval("/"+str+"/i") );
```

bye...

Comment: The eval is unnecessary.

Comment: It also creates two `RegExp` instances when only one is needed.